# ZK: dom-to-image screenshot script not working?

Tags: javascript, zk

Hi I am new to ZK and I am struggling to get my script working. I have tried creating testing the script on a HTML page which worked fine but it does not work in my ZK page

```html
<script>
   function captureScreen() {
      const screenshotTarget = document.body;
     
      domtoimage.toBlob(screenshotTarget).then(function (blob) { window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png'); });
      alert("alert box!!");
   }
</script>
```

the alert box was added as a test and it displays fine, however the script to take and download a screen capture does not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use this [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). Do you see any js error in your browser console?

In my 1st try, I found the error `saveAs is not a function`. Then I found I need to include [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

I have created a trivial example at
https://github.com/zkoss-demo/gettingStarted/tree/dom-to-image

If it doesn't help you locate the root cause, please attach related details including error message, zul page source...